# How to check if a character follows a string in a text file?

Tags: shell, awk, delimiter

Let's say we had this .txt file:

```
ABC;123
B;54
F;12
ABC;23
B;9
```

And wanted to only print the lines that contain the ABC identificator, that is the output should be:

```
ABC;123
ABC;23
```

However when I use this code

```
awk -F ';' '("ABC" ~ $1)' sof.txt
```

I get

```
ABC;123
B;54
ABC;23
B;9
```

Which is obviously not right. How can I check if a semicolon follows the given ID so that only the needed lines are printed?

Comment: Use `awk -F ';' '$1 ~ "ABC"' file` or `awk -F ';' '$1 ~ /^ABC$/' file` or `awk -F ';' '$1 == "ABC"' file`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/3yt6xI).

Comment: Or just `grep 'ABC;' sof.txt` (perhaps with `-i` and/or `-w` options, and/or a `^[[:space:]]*` in front of the regex, depending on your precise requirements).

Comment: FYI you had your comparison backwards, testing if the contents of `$1` matches the regexp `"ABC"` is written `$1 ~ "ABC"` which is only true if `$1` is `"ABC"` or contains a string that has `"ABC"` as a substring. By writing `"ABC" ~ $1` you were testing if the string `"ABC"` matched the regexp contained in `$1` which it does when `$1` contains any of the first field values from your input file except `F`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to match exactly `ABC` in 1st field then try something like:

```
awk -F';' '$1=="ABC"' Input_file
```

In case you want to check if its part of any value(in 1st field) then try:

```
awk -F';' '$1~/ABC/' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility.

With GNU `awk` also you can get a full field using word boundaries:

```
awk -F';' '$1 ~ /\<ABC\>/' file
ABC;123
ABC;23
```